# How to Click the hyper Links in the table columns of webpage using Selenium web driver and how to store it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my HTML Script:

1. How to capture the link element in the tenth row?
   [HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etjef.jpg)

   ```html
      <table id="dataTableParticipantSearchResults" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <thead>
           <tr align="left">
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="20%" style="width: 154px;">      
                 <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper"></div>
               </th>
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="20%" style="width: 96px;"></th>
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="15%" style="width: 69px;"></th>
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="10%" style="width: 44px;"></th>
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="20%" style="width: 156px;"></th>
               <th class="ui-state-default" width="15%" style="width: 68px;"></th> 
           </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr class="odd" align="left">
           <td><a href="LINK"></a></td>
      </tr>
   ```

2.How to store that value, so that i can call the same value to access the link element?

Comment: use XPath: http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can store the value in a WebElement and call any number of times.

WeElement link = table.findelement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='dataTableParticipantSearchResults']/tbody/tr/td[9]"));

now call it any number of times:

link.click();---------1st time

link.click();--------- 2nd time

and so on.....cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can always find these kinds of hyperlinks by first identifying the root table id- in this case it will be like this:

```
WebElement table = driver.findelement(by.id("dataTableParticipantSearchResults"));
```

Now you can use Xpath or Css Selector to select the link

try this:

```
table.findelement(by.cssSelector("a[href='LINK']")).click();
```

or try

```
table.findelement(by.linktext("LINK")).click();
```

or try

```
table.findelement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='dataTableParticipantSearchResults']/tbody/tr/td[0]")).click();
```

let me know if these work....cheers !

Comment: Thanks for the help, Its working by using  Css Selector to select the link. But here i have to give an entire link we is very big instead of it can i use any other to find element.           Also, when I use Xpath table.findelement(by.xpath(".//*[@id='dataTableParticipantSearchResults']/tbody/tr/td[0]")).click(); as the link is in the tenth row i placed dataTableParticipantSearchResults']/tbody/tr/td[10] but its not working. Can you please do needful

Comment: Why are using td[10]?? there is only one td so we have to use only td[0].
Please try with this and if it doesn't work i will let you know other approach as well.
Also please go through the below link for a better understanding of Xpath-
    http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/

Comment: That's great to hear from you again! Thank you. Here I used td[10] because the link which I want to click is in 10th row. So I used 10 in the place of 0. Please let me know.

Comment: That is not how the Xpath works - so if u want to click a link in 10th row u have to use then td[9], because xpath starts from td[0].

Comment: Its worked for me for td[9]..... but How to store that value, so that i can call the same value to access the same link element which contains same visible ID?

Comment: Hi Shamai, glad to know it worked, please accept my answer by clicking the tick symbol.
I would be happy to answer your next question for storing the value also.

Comment: please see above, my nswer to your 2nd question.!